# Open file for reading and writing(not appending) in perl

Tags: perl, file, file-io

Is there any way with the standard perl libraries to open a file and edit it, without having to close it then open it again? All I know how to do is to either read a file into a string close the file then overwrite the file with a new one; or read and then append to the end of a file.

The following currently works but; I have to open it and close it twice, instead of once:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;
use utf8; binmode(STDIN, ":utf8"); binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
use IO::File; use Cwd; my $owd = getcwd()."/"; # OriginalWorkingDirectory
use Text::Tabs qw(expand unexpand);
$Text::Tabs::tabstop = 4; #sets the number of spaces in a tab

opendir (DIR, $owd) || die "$!";
my @files = grep {/(.*)\.(c|cpp|h|java)/}  readdir DIR;
foreach my $x (@files){
    my $str;
    my $fh = new IO::File("+<".$owd.$x);
    if (defined $fh){
        while (<$fh>){ $str .= $_; }
        $str =~ s/( |\t)+\n/\n/mgos;#removes trailing spaces or tabs
        $str = expand($str);#convert tabs to spaces
        $str =~ s/\/\/(.*?)\n/\/\*$1\*\/\n/mgos;#make all comments multi-line.
        #print $fh $str;#this just appends to the file
        close $fh;
    }
    $fh = new IO::File(" >".$owd.$x);
    if (defined $fh){
        print $fh $str; #this just appends to the file
        undef $str; undef $fh; # automatically closes the file
    }
}
```

Comment: 1k + views and only 1 upvote . . .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You already opened the file for reading and writing by opening it with the mode `<+`, you're just not doing anything useful with it -- if you wanted to replace the contents of the file instead of writing to the current position (the end of the file) then you should `seek` back to the beginning, write what you need to, and then `truncate` to make sure that there's nothing left over if you made the file shorter.

But since what you're trying to do is inplace filtering of a file, might I suggest that you use perl's inplace editing extension, instead of doing all of the work yourself?

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Tabs qw(expand unexpand);
$Text::Tabs::tabstop = 4;

my @files = glob("*.c *.h *.cpp *.java");

{
   local $^I = ""; # Enable in-place editing.
   local @ARGV = @files; # Set files to operate on.
   while (<>) {
      s/( |\t)+$//g; # Remove trailing tabs and spaces
      $_ = expand($_); # Expand tabs
      s{//(.*)$}{/*$1*/}g; # Turn //comments into /*comments*/
      print;
    }
}
```

And that's all the code you need -- perl handles the rest. Setting the [$^I variable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlvar) is equivalent to using the [-i commandline flag](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlrun). I made several changes to your code along the way -- `use utf8` does nothing for a program with no literal UTF-8 in the source, `binmode`ing stdin and stdout does nothing for a program that never uses stdin or stdout, saving the CWD does nothing for a program that never `chdir`s. There was no reason to read each file in all at once so I changed it to linewise, and made the regexes less awkward (and incidentally, the `/o` regex modifier is good for almost precisely nothing these days, except adding hard-to-find bugs to your code).

Comment: @hobbs, The process is line-based. What if I want to use regexp that contains newline?

Comment: @solotim depends on the details. You may be able to change `$/` to something more appropriate than `"\n"` — in particular, if you set `$/` to `undef` then perl will read the entire file contents in one read, let you modify them, and then write back out. Memory is big enough that that's a reasonable approach for many files. But if it's not, you'll need to do the work on your own.